# Email attachment using rest API

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, attachment, ftp

I have a requirement to attach pdf document with my emails. And the pdf document changes with each email according to the system configuration.

Can you please help in understanding

1. how can I upload my PDFs to EnhanchedFtp?
2. What is the retention policy in EnhancedFtp
3. how can I refer them in my email? I know I can use AttachFile function, but how can I pass my pdf name which changes with each email.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't available through the Rest API right now.  If you would like more information on how to do this via the SOAP API, here is some helpful documentation.  You would need to create a Portfolio object, then retrieve that object for your e-mail send.

[Create Portfolio Object Code@ documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_portfolio_object_via_the_web_service_api/)

[Retrieve Portfolio Object Code@ documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_an_item_from_your_portfolio/)